# holding expression unevaluated in ActionMenu

Tags: button

for list `li1 = {"A", "B", "C"};` I would like to generate `ActionMenu` but that will be generated on the fly, and on selection will assign value that we don't know in advance (it must be computed) to some variable `k1`. Eg. in this example it will assign ordinal number of selected label, to `k1`. But this doesn't work, because it evaluate `Set` immediately, and does not wait for selection.

```
li1 = {"A", "B", "C"};
ActionMenu["select", RuleDelayed @@@ Thread[{#, Thread[Set[k1, Range[Length@#]]]}] &@li1]
```

I want that `Set[k1, somevalue]` wait for evaluation until selection.

Comment: Have you tried `Inactive` along with `Activate`?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, yes that's it.
`ActionMenu["select", Activate[RuleDelayed @@@ 
     Thread[{#, Thread[Inactive[Set][k1, Range[Length@#]]]}]]&@li1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `k1` is always the same you can do:

```
ActionMenu[
  "select"
, # :> Set[k1, #2] & @@@ Transpose[{#, Range[Length@#]}] &@li1
]
```